# Powershell - Adding to object

Tags: powershell

I'm creating an Object in Powershell and then converting it to JSON later to be used as part of a request body to an API.

```
$CardBody = @{
  "type" = "message"
  "summary" = "Azure Advisor"
  "attachments" = @(
    @{
      "contentType" = "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive"
      "contentUrl" = "null"
      "content" = @{
        '$schema' = "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json"
        "version" = "1.3"
        "type" = "AdaptiveCard"
        "body" = @(
          @{
            "size" ="large"
            "style"= "Heading"
            "text" = "**Azure Advisor**"
            "type" = "TextBlock"
            "wrap" = $false
          }
          @{
            "type" = "TextBlock" 
            "text" = "Test"
            "wrap" = $true
          }
        )
      }
    }
  )
}
```

I'd like to use a for loop to add additional elements to the `body` section of the object but I can't get it to work.

```
> $CardBody.attachments.content.body.gettype()   

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

```
> $CardBody.attachments.content.body | Get-Member

   TypeName: System.Collections.Hashtable

Name              MemberType            Definition
----              ----------            ----------
Add               Method                void Add(System.Object key, System.Object value), void IDictionary.Add(System.Object key, System.Object value)
Clear             Method                void Clear(), void IDictionary.Clear()
Clone             Method                System.Object Clone(), System.Object ICloneable.Clone()
Contains          Method                bool Contains(System.Object key), bool IDictionary.Contains(System.Object key)
ContainsKey       Method                bool ContainsKey(System.Object key)
ContainsValue     Method                bool ContainsValue(System.Object value)
```

It looks to be a hashtable with a method for adding values, but if I attempted to use add I get an error:

```
MethodException: 
Line |
  44 |      $teamsCardBody.attachments.content.body.Add("type", "TextBlock")
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot find an overload for "Add" and the argument count: "2".
MethodException:
```

Initially, I tried building a new object inside my for loop, which I then added to $CardBody.attachments.content.body. This did work, but then once I converted it to JSON, it wasn't formatted correctly.

I attempted this by using `New-Object` and `Add-Member`, then I added that object to the hashtable.

Powershell objects and types seem to forever confuse me :(. Is there a better way for me to approach the creation of the object to start with?

Comment: `$CardBody.attachments.content.body.gettype() ` is showing the type of `body` (an array), and `$CardBody.attachments.content.body | Get-Member` is showing the type of its contents (hashtables).  `$teamsCardBody.attachments.content.body.Add("type", "TextBlock")` is treating `body` as a hashtable, but it's the contents that support that syntax: 
 `$teamsCardBody.attachments.content.body[0].Add("type", "TextBlock")`.  Note that the hashtables already have 'type' properties, so this will still fail, but for a different reason!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to boxdog in the comments, once they'd pointed out that I was misinterpreting the `Get-Member` command, I just did this inside my loop:

```
    # Build a hashtable
    $newCardBody = @{
      "type" = "TextBlock"
      "text" = $costSummary
      "wrap" = $true
      "separator" = $true
    }

    # Append the new hashtable to the "body" array
    $CardBody.attachments.content.body += $newCardBody
```